# Failed to connect to the device

Tags: windows-phone-7

Failed to connect to the device. Ensure that the device is completely booted and is connected...  Thats what I've been getting for the past 24 hours when I try to deploy to my wp7 device.  This have happened to me before but its always temporally.

-I try restarting pc and wp7 phone.
-different usb ports and cables.
-creating another user (running windows 8 enterprise)
-Re-installing vs skd 7.1.1

Right now Im installing the whole sdk (not just the update as before) and see if it works.

Besides that I can't run the emulator on windows 8.  Always shut downs.

Any other suggestions?

Comment: Does Zune picks up your device when you connect it to your computer?

Comment: It's not really a question for StackOverflow. You should ask that on the official Windows Phone forums: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-us/wptools/threads